# Почему эти строки разные по версии MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть запись в базе (колонка `h1_ru`):

> Гриппофлю от простуды и гриппа

И я пытаюсь найти ее таким запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `h1_ru` LIKE 'Гриппофлю от простуды и гриппа'
```

В итоге ничего не находит. То есть по сути это какие-то разные символы, но выглядят они одинаково...

Как привести базу к единым символам UTF-8

Кодировка таблиц utf8_general_ci

Comment: *по сути это какие-то разные символы, но выглядят они одинаково...* `SELECT HEX(h1_ru) ..` поможет увидеть разницу. PS. Использовать LIKE при поиске по точному значению вместо `=` - это.. ммм.. не очень разумно.

Comment: *Кодировка таблиц utf8_general_ci* А сервера? а базы? а поля? а соединения? Укажите, в конце концов, явный COLLATE при сравнении.